# How to create image with ImageMagick?

Tags: ruby, image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, minimagick

I need to dynamically create an image, and I'm trying to find a good 'starting place' using `magick` or `convert` from command line (the actual library I will convert the CLI command to is MiniMagick for ruby)

To be honest, it's a little bit overwhelming... I'm not asking someone to write the whole thing for me, just get me a good 'starting' place that I can then work on adding text "layers" to.

Here is what the final output image needs to look like, and the required things I'm looking for:

1. A background image (the gray circle) that I can position using `x,y` coordinates. The input file is `circle.png`. I'd also like to be able to enlarge/reduce the dimensions of the circle to be the exact size i want.
2. Red small, centered text.
3. Bold, larger, centered black text. For this text it needs to intelligently go on new lines when the line is too long (and have padding against the outside of the image so it doesn't touch the edge)
4. Blue, underlined, medium text thats centered.
5. A red border that overlays the background image

[image]

`circle.png` for reference

[image]

Comment: Please post circle.png. See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/ and https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/ and https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert

Comment: Posted! I will look at these in the meantime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you a start using ImageMagick to create your image. Unix syntax. ImageMagick does not have an underline feature. So you need to select an underline font for that section. (However, there are slightly more complex ways to achieve that using label: and then splicing in the underline)

```
convert -size 299x249 xc:white \( circle.png -resize 200x200 \) \
-gravity northwest -geometry +100+70 -compose over -composite \
-bordercolor red -border 1 \
-font arial -fill red -pointsize 18 -gravity north -annotate +0+20 "**Info**" \
-font arial -fill blue -pointsize 28 -gravity south -annotate +0+50 "click here" \
\( -size 279x -background none -fill black \
-font arial -pointsize 28 -gravity center \
caption:"Welcome John to your profile, have a look around" -trim +repage \) \
-gravity center -geometry +0-20 -compose over -composite \
result.png
```

NOTE: updated slightly

[image]

Comment: holy crap... you are insane at this.... i liteally just spent like 2 hours and got '**************' to appear but it wasn't listening to my position. WOW

Comment: Can you answer me this... how come it was trying to save 2 files with `-0` and `-1`?

Comment: Damn this is seriously great... thank you again so much. I will modify it now

Comment: What do the `\( ... \)` represent?

Comment: Also how do i make bold text? I tried to use `stroke` but it comes out quite funky

Comment: Found the answer, needed to use `convert -list font` and choose the appropriate one

Comment: `@Tallboy`  convert is for ImageMagick 6. Use magick rather than convert for ImageMagick 7. For windows remove \ from \( ... \) and change end of line \ to ^. Parentheses mean basically do a separate convert to process the command inside the parentheses. You should not be getting -0 and -1 unless your command still has two images in the command sequence. But if processed correctly, my command should only produce one result. If that is not the case for you, check your command or let me know. Show your code in that case.

Comment: CONTINUED: For bold, you use -stroke "yourcolor" -strokewidth x, where x is an integer, typically > 1.

Comment: Thanks! Your amazing answer helped me create the other images I needed to. This was my only remaining question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614225/imagemagick-why-wont-this-text-expand-to-fill

Comment: Caption: is what you need to have multiple lines and expand to your desired width with a given pointsize as I showed above.