# ImageMagick: Why won't this text expand to fill?

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm reading the [text handling docs](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label) for `label` and it seems if I specify `-size` it should magically get as big as possible to fill the space.

I want to make it so this text gets as big as possible. I will set the `\n` characters myself in the title (if absolutely necessary).

I'd rather the `\n` get calculated automatically, but it seems `label` is what makes it the biggest possible (but doesn't support automatic `\n`), while `caption` will add `\n` where appropriate (but doesn't support a dynamic size which fills to fit a space).

My goal is to basically get the BIGGEST possible text, whether it's on 1 line or 3, to fit in the green box (between the 2 red `******` lines).

Below are 2 examples of how it won't change. The green color is just temporary so I can debug.

Heres my code for this text piece (without all the rest):

```
-size 290x54 -background green -fill blue -font ArialB -gravity center label:'Join Us'
```

Multiline...

```
-size 290x54 -background green -fill blue -font ArialB -gravity center label:'Join Us Tomorrow\nFor An HVAC Meeting'
```

I don't know if this is possible, but ideally it should ask "if the title is on 1 line, what is the max size it could be? if I put a `\n` after word 1, what is the max size it could be? if i put a `\n` after word 2, what is the max size it could be?"... and then choosing the largest of those.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Label: will not expand to full width if you put in \n. If you want to have it full width and multiline, leave off \n and use caption: with specifying only the width (no height) and your desired pointsize.

Comment: But what if I want the pointsize to change to become the biggest text possible to fit the box? (like in the text docs, how anthony fills to fit the space). Sometimes the title will be only 3 words, and i want it to be huge, other times it will be 5 or 10 words and i want it to be as big as possible but not as big

Comment: I added 2 images that might be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command works for me with one correction. Apparently, the pointsize leaks from the your main command into the parenthesis processing, even though I added -respect-parenthesis. So the solution is to add +pointsize into the parenthesis command. Here is my command and result.

```
magick -respect-parenthesis -size 298x248 canvas:white \( 'arrows.png' -resize 300x \) -gravity northwest -geometry +0+140 -compose over -composite -bordercolor '#cccccc' -border 1 -font Arial -fill red -pointsize 22 -gravity north -annotate +0+4 '*************************' -font Arial -fill red -pointsize 22 -gravity north -annotate +0+68 '*************************' -font Arial -fill green -pointsize 15 -gravity south -annotate +0+64 'hvac.com' \( -size 279x55 +pointsize -background green -fill blue -font ArialB -gravity center caption:'test headline' \) -gravity center -geometry +0-82 -compose over -composite  output.png
```

Note that I put the arrows.png file where I could access it at the same level as where the command is being issued. You can change the path to it.

[image]

Comment: You are a god among men... I will try in about 10 mins https://giphy.com/gifs/iiS84hOJXh1Pq

Comment: It works!!! God you are so awesome... thank you. HVAC plumbing sites around the world will thank you

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick use caption by specifying both the widthxheight but not the pointsize. ImageMagick will figure out the proper pointsize to fill the text to the box. For example:

```
convert -size 500x200 -background white -font arial -fill black -gravity center caption:"Testing" -bordercolor red -border 1 test1.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 500x200 -background white -font arial -fill black -gravity center caption:"Should Be Bigger" -bordercolor red -border 1 test2.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 500x200 -background white -font arial -fill black -gravity center caption:"This is a title that will be fairly long and I want it to fit nicely" -bordercolor red -border 1 test3.png
```

[image]

You can also include the pointsize, so long as your text is not too long for the area of the box.

```
convert -size 500x200 -background white -font arial -fill black -pointsize 48 -gravity center caption:"Testing" -bordercolor red -border 1 test1b.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 500x200 -background white -font arial -fill black -pointsize 48 -gravity center caption:"Should Be Bigger" -bordercolor red -border 1 test2b.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 500x200 -background white -font arial -fill black -pointsize 48 -gravity center caption:"This is a title that will be fairly long and I want it to fit nicely" -bordercolor red -border 1 test3b.png
```

[image]

However, if you choose a font that is too big, you will get this:

```
convert -size 500x200 -background white -font arial -fill black -pointsize 64 -gravity center caption:"This is a title that will be fairly long and I want it to fit nicely" -bordercolor red -border 1 test3c.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. that is what I tried but I get this: https://imgur.com/a/9hO2w -- here is the code I'm using. It's in ruby and not imagemagick command line, but the `stack.do |stack| ... end` is the same as `\( ... \)`: https://imgur.com/a/79Hjw

Comment: Actually here is the full code if other parts of the command might be affecting it: https://imgur.com/a/oD4e7

Comment: I highlighted just the headline portion before taking the screenshot (its about halfway down, the part that generates what you see above)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know ruby. What version of ImageMagick is being used by Ruby (RMagick?)

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-22

Comment: My commands above should use "magick" rather than "convert" for IM 7. I get the same results using IM 7.0.7.22 and magick as I got above for IM 6 and convert. Perhaps your Rmagick requires IM 6 rather than IM 7 or you need to use magick in your commands when using IM 7 rather than convert.

Comment: oooooh i see. thank you! I will try seeing if theres a command to just run 'magick'. What is the difference anyway? Why are they so closely related and all the same commands work, but they operate differently?

Comment: Is there a way to get it to work with `convert`? It seems I don't have access to a 'magick' command.

Comment: if its not possible i will probably just see about modifying the ruby library to support it

Comment: I do not know ruby or Rmagick. But with ImageMagick 7, you can install the legacy convert components, but that will be using the older IM 6 code. The issue is whether Ruby/Rmagick is expecting IM 6 or IM 7. Even if it is compatible with IM 7, it may be expecting the IM 7 magick command rather than the IM 6 convert. If it can use IM 7 in legacy mode with convert, then you have to install IM 7 such that it can use the legacy code. For Windows this is a special flag when installing. For Mac and Unix, a symbolic link is use and may already be in place. You need to check with the Rmagick developers

Comment: Well RMagick is just a wrapper for Imagemagick, but thanks... i will try rto figure that out. Thank you!! That explains why what you wrote in my other answer didnt work quite right.

Comment: ok... I've tried converting the ruby into command line to eliminate that as a cause, and it's still not working. `magick --version` returns `Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-22 Q16 x86_64 2018-01-22 http://www.imagemagick.org`. Here is the command I'm running, and a sample image that it generates.

Comment: command: https://ybin.me/p/1219716c2009163f#a0Yl+iedli+sdpSJB8t17esbXlhLQinWBCTE31ixCeU=

Comment: Where is the arrows.png file? It does not show in your result. Is it accessible at the path you provided? Please provide that image, so your command can be tested. I also do not see the text for 'hvac.com' in your output. Are you sure you are actually running that command? Is your output from the command line or from your Rmagick?

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the full, non-cropped image because the other part I didn't think was related. I'll upload the arrows file and the full output. I'm using imagemagick only from CLI (`magick` command). I'm not using ruby, rmagick, or anything else anymore to eliminate possible variables. arrows.png: https://i.imgur.com/2qhsgz2.png -- heres an example of the full output -- https://i.imgur.com/1u1CcSs.png

Comment: Curious that someone down-voted my answer! I wonder what the reason for that? What was wrong with my answer? Too bad people do not give reasons for their down-voting. It would be helpful to know why, so that one does not repeat the mistakes.

Comment: Maybe it's just people being lame. It's definitely an awesome answer. To make up for it Ill upvote some of your other comments :)